# DBD::SQLite: sqlite_unicode Pragma

Tags: perl, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

When I connect with DBI/DBD::SQLite to a sqlite database without setting the `sqlite_unicode` pragma, is then used the `sqlite_unicode` setting the database was created with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not a [pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html), it's a setting that controls whether DBD::SQLite is to decode text or not.